# foreach statement causes undefined variable fileNameToStore in multiple file upload

Tags: php, sql, laravel, visual-studio-code

Im trying to upload more than a single file so I try to modify the code a little bit. But everytime I'm adding foreach($request->file('image') as $file). I always get an error about having undefined variable. I attached my controller code below, Any idea how can I fix this and make the multiple file upload?

```
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('image') as $file)
        {
        $filenameWithExt =$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images', $fileNameToStore);
        }
    }
    $post = new Post;
    $post->image = $fileNameToStore;
    $post->save();
    return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Post Created!');
```

Here is the create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Upload Images</h1>
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method'=> 'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])!!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::file('image',['multiple'=>'true', 'files'=>'true'])}}
    </div>
    
   {{Form::submit('Submit',['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}
   {!!Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: Can I show Form ?

Comment: can you post your error ? `undefined variable` what ?

Comment: {!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method'=> 'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'])!!}
<div class="form-group">
        {{Form::file('cover_image',['multiple'=>'true', 'files'=>'true'])}}
    </div>
{{Form::submit('Submit',['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}
    {!!Form::close()!!}

Comment: Im getting Undefined variable: fileNameToStore error

Comment: @Kaye i think you should put your html as well so we can see it's multiple image array and can write full solution for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correct understand you. Try to add `fileNameToStore` variable in `foreach`:

```
$errors = [];
$post = new Post;
if ($request->hasFile('cover_image')) {
    foreach ($request->file('cover_image') as $file) {
        $filenameWithExt =$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        $path = $request->file('image')->move('public/images', $fileNameToStore);
        $post->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;
    }
    if (! fileNameToStore) {
        $errors[] = false;
    }
    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('error', 'Somthing went wrong!');
    }
}
$post->save()
return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Post Created!');
```

Hope help you. PS replace `image` with `cover_image`.

Comment: Wow it worked ! but no file uploaded. It just say post created but not file in the folder

Comment: @Kaye could you please to check upload directory permission

Comment: @Kaye I edited my answer. I think you need replace `$request->file('image')->storeAs` with `$request->file('image')->move`

Comment: Oh I didn't noticed your edit. It's working now. Thanks Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

your getting `Undefined variable: fileNameToStore`  it means you not getting file and still try to access `$fileNameToStore` so you need to add this to inside if condition like this

```php
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    foreach ($request->file('image') as $file) {

        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
        $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images', $fileNameToStore);
    }
    $post = new Post;
    $post->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;
    $post->save();
    return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Post Created!');
}
return redirect('/dashboard')->with('error', 'Somthing went wrong!');
```

> **NOTE** this is only solution for `Undefined variable: fileNameToStore` not upload image thing

Comment: how can I fix my code in order for the multiple file upload to work?

Comment: is `$request->file('image')` this array of images ? are your usre

Comment: im not really sure. Im just new in studying laravel

Comment: try `dd($request->file('image'))` and check

Comment: Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1216 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "img1.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "phpA275.tmp"
  basename: "phpA275.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpA275.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpA275.tmp"
  aTime: 2021-04-08 11:30:20
  mTime: 2021-04-08 11:30:20
  cTime: 2021-04-08 11:30:20
  inode: 0
  size: 29888
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false

Comment: it is single file seems